# Confusion on – File f = new File(....); if(f.exists()) {…}

Tags: java, android

In most other languages / operating system I've worked with, a statement like

> File f = new File(....);

would attempt to open the file, and either create one if it didn't exist, or return an error code if it was missing. So, what happens in java.io? I'd like to understand the mindset of the run time engine. Can I actually get a handle to a non-existent file? Dose the java run time engine hold off on making the file until the 1st time I write to it? If not, shouldn't

> if(f.exists()) {…}

always be “true”?
- any comments welcome - Joe

Comment: Start by reading the javadoc for `File`. Specifically the first line.

Comment: I've been reading most of the day, and I'm assuming this is the correct way too see if a file exists, but I hate making assumptions. I also don't want to start inadvertently making files by accident. Could you at least throw me a good url/link that explains why java seems to work this way? - Thanks - Joe

Comment: If you google `File javadoc`, you will fall on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). The first line reads `An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.` In other words, a `File` has no relation to the file system, it's just a name.

Comment: Read JavaDoc on [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to better understand the specifics of File Class in Java. I must emphasize that everything in Java is an Object, even a File, which is a collection of related data on a disk can be represented by an object, whose template in the case is File Class. The URL i mentioned tells a detailed explanation of the class itself and its various methods on which its behavior depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a File by creating a reference to a non existing File. If you pass that File to a FileOutputsteam the Stream will create the File on your drive.

So if you cant be certain that the File doesnt exist you need to be able to check its existence with `f.exists()` othwerwise you wouldnt be able to make an intelligent decision on how to proceed

Comment: Ahh, so just getting a File object to the file in question only get's it's info, and nothing happens until I attach a FileOutputStream to it? Thanks much. I'm going to plow ahead now and will mark the answer correct as soon as I'm sure I understand what you said correctly - Thanks - Joe

Comment: Yeah nothing happens, except that you reference a file object. By just creating the File you cant be certain that there actually is a file with the given name at the given location. You would have to check that first, before doing anything productive with the file.

Comment: Thanks Daniel: That seems to have solved the current problem. I marked the answer as correct. I already have more problems to solve tomorrow - Like when I perform a "String mDirName = mDir.getPath(); " on the file returned from getExternalStorageDirectory(); I end up with a /0 (seems to be an ASCII '0' not a binary zero that doesn't seem right
/, s, t, o, r, a, g, e, /, e, m, u, l, a, t, e, d, /, 0,, but that will be tomorrows question (if I can't solve it myself).

Comment: you simply dont compare string with the == operator, use a.equals(b)

Answer (score 5):

As described in the Javadoc, `java.io.File` represents a path, not a file. Bad naming. Think of operations on `File` as path operations, because that's what they are. Unless something specifically says that it creates a file at a given path, it doesn't.

Comment: I hit the up arrow on this one for the explanation on 
"File  represents a path, not a file. Bad naming." but I already read and used Daniel's answer befor I read this, and so I marked his as the correct answer - Thanks - Joe

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Developers official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) you can read that a `File` is:

> An "abstract" representation of a file system entity identified by a
>   pathname.
>
> **The actual file referenced by a File may or may not exist.** It may
>   also, despite the name File, be a directory or other non-regular file.